# Mysql group by month with null values if 0 entities

Tags: mysql

Really simple (can't find an example on here). Basically I want to add in the null values for missing months.

Currently I have

```
|month| total |
----------------
   2  | 2454.34
   3  | 1254.34
```

Where as I want

```
|month| total |
----------------
   1  |    0
   2  | 2454.34
   3  | 1254.34
   4  |    0
   5  |    0
   6  |    0
```

And so on.

My query so far

```
SELECT MONTH(bookings.booking) as month, SUM(bookings.tendered) as total
FROM bookings 
INNER JOIN salons ON salons.id = bookings.salon_id
WHERE bookings.paid = 1
AND YEAR(bookings.booking) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(bookings.booking)
ORDER BY MONTH(bookings.booking);
```

I did try the following but doesn't seem to work the way I want it to? Excuse the different formats from above example

```
SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Jan', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Jan',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Feb', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Feb',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Mar', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Mar',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Apr', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Apr',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'May', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'May',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Jun', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Jun',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Jul', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Jul',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Aug', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Aug',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Sep', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Sep',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Oct', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Oct',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Nov', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Nov',
        SUM(IF(MONTH(bookings.booking) = 'Dec', bookings.tendered, 0)) AS 'Dec',
        SUM(tendered) AS total
```

**UPDATED**

```
select `a`.`month` as `month_int`, IFNULL(SUM(bookings.tendered), 0) as total from `bookings` right join (
SELECT 1 as month
UNION SELECT 2 as month
UNION SELECT 3 as month
UNION SELECT 4 as month
UNION SELECT 5 as month
UNION SELECT 6 as month
UNION SELECT 7 as month
UNION SELECT 8 as month
UNION SELECT 9 as month
UNION SELECT 10 as month
UNION SELECT 11 as month
UNION SELECT 12 as month\n
) a  on `a`.`month` = MONTH(bookings.booking) where `bookings`.`paid` = ? and date(`bookings`.`booking`) > ? and `salon_id` in (?, ?, ?) group by `a`.`month`
```

Comment: You can left join your query to `(SELECT 1 AS Month UNION ALL SELECT 2 ... UNION ALL SELECT 12)`

Comment: @shmosel that's a good idea thanks I'll give it a go! Laravel query builder isn't that greeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work

```
SELECT m.MONTH as month, 
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(b.total) > 0 THEN SUM(b.total) 
    ELSE 0 END as total
FROM
(
 SELECT '01' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '02' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '03' AS   
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '04' AS
 MONTH 
 UNION SELECT '05' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '06' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '07' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '08' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '09' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '10' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '11' AS
 MONTH
 UNION SELECT '12' AS
 MONTH
 ) AS m
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MONTH(b.bookings) AS 'month', SUM(b.tendered) AS 'total' 
 FROM bookings AS b
 INNER JOIN salons AS s 
 ON s.id = b.salon_id
 WHERE b.paid = 1
 AND YEAR(b.booking) = 2017) AS n
ON 
m.MONTH = n.month
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see this example online : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bbf0/1

```
SELECT
  idMonth,
  MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(idMonth, '%m')) as m,
  IFNULL(sum(Bookings.price), 0) as total
FROM Bookings
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 2 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 3 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 4 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 5 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 6 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 7 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 8 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 9 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 10 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 11 as idMonth
  UNION SELECT 12 as idMonth
) as Month
ON Month.idMonth = month(`date`)
GROUP BY Month.idMonth
```

Comment: I like your answer :) Although I've tried to apply this and I get the same result as before. I'm using 5.7.14 if that makes any difference? I've added the full query print out from the query builder in the anwer

Comment: Thx for your new code example but what is your result? I do not see any problem